# print line number of output in shell script

Tags: shell, pipeline

I have a script that prints out the average time when pinging a server, shown below:

```
ping -c3 "${I}" | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2 | sed 's/$/\tms/'
```

How can I add the line number to output of the script above when pinging a list of servers ??

my actual output when pinging list of 3 host is:

```
6.924 ms
100.099 ms
7.756 ms
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
1,6.924 ms
2,100.099 ms
3,7,756 ms
```

so that this can be read by excel :)
Thank in advanced!!

Comment: Are those commands in a loop?

Comment: exactly :) In a for loop :)

Comment: I'm confused by your output.  The `sed` in your example looks like it is putting a tab before the "ms".  Do you want a tab or a space?

Comment: I just want a space there :) but actually a tab is good also :)

Answer (score 2):

Pipe your output through perl:

```
echo -e 'aa\nbb' | perl -ne 'print $., ",", $_'
```

Output:

```
1,aa
2,bb
```

Comment: +1 or awk: `| awk '{print NR "," $0}'`. You could also write `perl -pe 's/^/$.,/'`

Comment: OP is looping through a command and its output is only a single line for each iteration. Hence, I think this approach is not valid for this case.

Comment: @jkshah answered before the comment clarifications. He could still pipe his entire script output through perl, but agree that it is not optimal in this case.

Comment: Just pipe the loop into perl/awk: `for host in $list; do ...; done | perl -pe 's/^/$.,/'`

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you want?

```
C=1
for I in 'host1' 'host2' 'host3'
do
  ping -c3 "${I}" | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2 | echo "$C,$(sed 's/$/\tms/')"
  C=$((C+1))
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard tool for line numbering is `nl`.  Pipe your output to `nl -s,`  That is:

```
for I; do
  ping -c3 "${I}" | awk -F/ 'END{print $5, "\tms"}' 
done | nl -s,
```

Since you haven't specified how the list is generated, I'm just showing the case where the list of hosts to be pinged is given on the command line.  Note that this introduces leading whitespace before the line number, so you might want to filter that through `sed` to remove.

Of course, this script is spending most of its time waiting for the ping, and you probably want to speed it up by running the pings in parallel.  In that case, it is better to add the line number at the beginning so you can get a stable sort in the output:

```
line=1
{ for I; do ping -c3 $I | awk -F/ 'END{
     printf( "%d,%s\tms\n", line,$5 )}' line=$line &
     : $((line +=1 ))
done; wait; } | sort -n
```

In this case, the `wait` is not necessary since `sort` will block until all of the pings have closed their output, but the `wait` becomes necessary if you add any processes in the pipeline before the `sort` that do not necessarily wait for all of their input before doing any processing, so it is a good practice to leave the `wait` in place.